# pandas read_csv and setting na_values to any string in the csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

> data.csv
>
> 1, 22, 3432
>
> 1, 23, \N
>
> 2, 24, 54335
>
> 2, 25, 3928

I have a csv file of data that is collected from a device. Every now and then the device doesn't relay information and outputs '\N'. I want to treat these as NaN and did this by doing

```
read_csv(data.csv, na_values=['\\N'])
```

which worked fine. However, I would prefer to have not only this string turned to NaN but any string that is in the csv file just in case the data I get in the future has a different string.

Is it possible to me to make any changes in the argument so it covers all strings?

Comment: I mean if I should get data that looks, for example, like 'Kud'. I would like my script to be as flexible as possible so it keep working in the case that '\\N' was changed. Note: '\\N' doed not appear in the csv file. It looks like \N just in case it looks confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to manually pass all the keywords as a list or dict to `na_values`

> na_values : list-like or dict, default None

Alternatively, use [pd.to_numeric](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas-to-numeric) and set errors to `coerce` to convert all values to numeric after reading the csv file.

sample input `df`:

```
    A   B        
0   1   2         
1   0  \N      
2  \N   8       
3  11   5       
4  11  Kud   

df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

output:

```
     A     B        
0    1     2         
1    0   NaN      
2  NaN     8       
3   11     5       
4   11   NaN
```